# Rocket-assisted drag cancellation in artillery shell

Tags: projectile, drag, aerodynamics, rocket-science

The main limit on artillery range is drag. Hence for the same muzzle velocity, the WWII 800mm Schwerer supergun had twice the range of the modern 155mm M777 gun, because the super shell had a much greater ballistic coefficient.

Now, I want to compare two approaches to compensating for drag.

The first is increasing muzzle velocity.

The second is more complex. We mount a rocket motor behind the shell that exactly cancels the drag out at all points in flight.

For a given shell and range, and assuming we have the minimum muzzle velocity to reach the range in vacuum, which method will use less propellant?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an answer, but:

1. The rocket motor and its propellent will increase the mass of the shell.  More initial propellent would be needed to attain the same muzzle velocity.
2. On the other hand, with a motor, the muzzle velocity could be less resulting in less initial propellent and lower drag forces.

I think one would have to do the numbers.